# How to share free dynamic DNS domain on Facebook?

Tags: dns, facebook

I'm hosting some websites on my raspberry behing my box and I'm using [changeip.com](https://www.changeip.com) to have a free DNS service...

But then, when I would like to post my website's link to facebook or set it as my dedicated facebook page's website an error occurs and I can't update page's data :

[image: Non significant facebook error]

I am using Let's Encrypt SSL certificates too (does it impact on something ?)

Is there a way to get arround this ?

Comment: Is this better for the title ? ... I don't know where to start that's the problem ... I've actually contact them but no answer :/

Comment: Your title simply needs to succinctly communicate your problem. This one looks better.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for the moment I'm using an URL shortener such as [Bit.do](https://bit.do/) or even [Bitly](https://bitly.com/) ( but for this one I'm facing some warning message on redirect ...

But Well that's not a true answer IMO